# Getting Stuck on Importing utils, Constants, config

Tags: python

This the first time. I am trying to set up this bot where it has different py elements. They are all in the same folder but when I run the code I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

```
import time, math, random, os
import utils, constants, config
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from utils import prRed, prYellow, prGreen

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Can you help if on how to resolve it ?

Comment: Please confirm that the directory containing your script has a file named `utils.py`. Please show a list of the files in the directory where you are running your script.

Comment: How are you running your script? From an editor or IDE? From the command line? Is the folder with the scripts in it your current working directory?

Answer (score -1):

After my a few attempts, it may help you.

1. You can try to type `pip install utils` in your terminal.
2. If your computer tells you the `pip` command is not available then you can add the full path where pip is installed to your PATH. e.g. `/usr/bin/pip install utils`
3. If your OS is Linux, you can try `sudo apt install pip`.